# jQuery - find the specified components on the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm searching for `inputs` on my form and adding them to the `inputs` variable:

```
var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(".input:visible:enabled");
```

How can I extend this search of the other components like `select`. So, add the `inputs` and `selects` in the order in which they were found on the `form`?

Something like

```
var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(".input:visible:enabled OR .select");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).parents("form").find(".input:visible:enabled, .select");
```

**Multiple selectors will be separated by comma(`,`).**

For more see [here](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: Omg, I'm idiot, I've tried it, but choose the wrong component. It works, thanks :-)

Comment: @DvirAzulay Brother, I give my answer before 60sec, how do I copy you? A request to you, don't blame anyone without knowing.

Comment: I saw it, thecodeparadox was really a bit sooner but edited his answer one minute after, that's why I answer him at first...

Comment: @thecodeparadox, because after I posted my answer I saw yours with only the first line. I decided to keep mine because it had explanation and a link. Then you edited and included the same two lines I have in mine, even formatted like mine... but, who cares. Just don't call me a liar.

Comment: @DvirAzulay How can a I call my brother a lier? If you hurt by me then sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can separate selectors with a comma (`,`)

[jQuery Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)